# Rails 4.2: How to force to reload model definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a model `payment_request.rb` in our Rails 4.2 app and we would like to force to reload it with `before_action` in its controller `payment_requests_controller.rb`. Is there a way doing reloading?

Comment: This seems like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/135952): why do you want to do this? Is there a better way? I'm finding it hard to imagine a situation where I would actually want to do this in production code, and the ones I can think of are sufficiently esoteric that no one who wouldn't already themselves think of [twonegatives' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36172473/27358) should try it. (Note that in dev recent Rails [should do this automatically](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#reloading) when source files change.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Mariah suggested you a way to reload an instance of a model class, but in case your intention was to really reload the definition of a class, you could do it with this trick:

```
before_action :reload_model

def reload_model
  Object.send(:remove_const, :PaymentRequest)
  load 'app/models/payment_request.rb'
end
```

Beware of side effects like impossibility to access a `PaymentRequest` from other parts of same instance of your application during that class is reloading. Actually I doubt if doing this in your controller code is a right thing.

Reloading a class may be useful when some constant value should be updated (as it is filled upon first class loading and changed during time). But in case this situation occurs during your application is live, you'd better consider changing constant-based solution to something more appropriate.

Comment: ` impossibility to access a PaymentRequest from other parts of same instance of your application` - Will others user be affected by reloading? Our app is multi tenant.

Comment: @user938363 I believe it depends on the way your application is hosted (threads, processes, web and application server and so on) and used. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by multitenant, but you're definetly in a risk. In case there are other ways besides class reloading, I'd suggest to use them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reload the model class you can use this

```
ModelClassName.reset_column_information
```

API Documentation on [reset_column_information](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class)

Answer (score 0):

You want the model to reload when? Not sure why you would want a reload on a before_action, you can simply just call "@payment_request.reload" in any method

If you want it in a before action you would have to add this before_action in your controller. you will also have to define a function that it calls. For example,

```
before_action :reload

def reload 
    @payment_request.reload
end
```

Comment: We are looking for reload the class definition.